# How can i pass values of latlng array list to polygon

Tags: java, android

I stored coordinates in firebase. and are always retrieved as an arraylist of type latlng.
My question is how can i pass the values of the array which are coordinates to the polygonpolygon.

Here is what i tried.

```
private void DrawPolygon(List<LatLng> array) {
    int length = array.size();
    // Store a data object with the polygon, 
    // used here to indicate an arbitrary type.
    PolygonOptions poly = new PolygonOptions();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        poly.add(new LatLng(array.get(i).latitude, array.get(i).longitude));
    }
}
```

On runtime, the polygon array does not get populated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the array for validity before trying to populate the polygon. Could be that the values in the referenced array are empty.

```
private void DrawPolygon(List<LatLng> array) {

int length = array.size();
// Store a data object with the polygon, 
// used here to indicate an arbitrary type.
PolygonOptions poly = new PolygonOptions();

for(int i = 0; i < length; i++){
    if(array.get(i).latitude != null &&
        array.get(i).longitude != null){
        LatLng latLong = new LatLng(array.get(i).latitude,       
                              array.get(i).longitude);
        poly.add(latLong);
    }   
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it says `Operator '!=' cannot be applied to 'double', 'null'`

Comment: Thanks  i made a few tweaks to the code you provided and it finally worked